# Anonymous subscribers does not get expired in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have a Merge replication with anonymous subscribers, in my sysmergesubscriptions there are old subscriptions that still has the status 1 (active) and the last_sync_date is way below the retentionperiod, in fact all of the subscriptions in the table has the status of active!?

The job "Expired subscription clean up" runs every night without errors but does not seem to set them to inactive. I have tried to follow the stored procedures that it uses to understand but I do not really follow.

Do anybody know why this is happening or have some input to what i should investigate?

Comment: I like to add my progress in this if someone else has this problem. It seems that there is actually something that is being done to these subscriptions. They do not get set to inactive but the flag cleanedup_unsent_changes gets set after retention period is reached. this excludes the subscriptions in code evaluating active generations for example in metadata cleanup.